# Change date format validation, mvc 3 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, date

I been struggeling with this problem for two days now and have still not found the solution...
I have added a datepicker to my website using this tutorial:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Everything works except for the validation. I keep getting the error "Please enter a valid date".
I have changed everything in my solution to "dd-MM-yyyy" and added
        globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK"

to my web.config. I still dosent work. Keep getting the error. Should I maybe changemy model class?
The date I want to validate:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateOfBooking { get; set; }
```

Tried with:

```
    $('#formatdate').change(function () {
        $('#datpicker').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
    });
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function getDateYymmdd(value) {
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    return $.datepicker.parseDate("dd-mm-yy", value);
}
$('.date').each(function () {
    var minDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-min"));
    var maxDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-max"));
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy",  // hard-coding uk date format, but could embed this     as an attribute server-side (based on the current culture)
        minDate: minDate,
        maxDate: maxDate
    });
});
});
```

Tried many different solutions but nothing seems to work. Cant figure out if the problem is in the mvc or jquery.
Someone please help :) Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to manually test parseDate, just by putting a validate date in there and seeing if it works.

Comment: No I havent. This is my first time working with jquery and its a little confusing :) Not sure how the validate works and where it goes on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the jquery.validate plugin which doesn't recognize this format. I would recommend you the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx). You could use the [globalize plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) in order to set the preferred culture for client side validation.

Comment: Its a little hard understanding the links you suggested since im not used to working with jquery. Could you give a few more clues? :)

Comment: Okay... after a few more hours it seems like im making a little progress. When I select a date everything works. Even the validate... until i change the date. Then I get the message "Please select a valid date". I have two date fiels and it seems like its a little random for when the date is valid or not. Very strange... Any guess for why its like that??